# Preventing duplicate form submission when clicking the submit button multiple times

Tags: struts2, duplicates, token

I'm working on a webapp project with struts2 and I would like to prevent making duplicate entries when a form submit button is clicked multiple times. I'd prefer to handle this issue in the server side to make sure browser compatibility. The webapp follows the workflow FORM -> ACTION (which in most cases, validateSave() then save()) -> RESULTPAGE(which is a jsp). I am using "continue" to link the FORM->RESULT page. I have read that redirection would be better but in some cases I am setting a bean(scope is request) in the ACTION that is needed to properly load the RESULT page.

This is where I am having trouble with TokenSession. I am able to skip the saving if the request is a duplicate but I am not able to set the bean properly to load the RESULT page.

Would Appreciate any help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

As Struts 2 provides `token interceptor` that can we used to handle multiple form submission problem.

http://www.journaldev.com/2281/struts2-token-interceptor-to-handle-double-form-submission-problem

Comment: I've tried this, both token and token-session interceptor but it did not give me the result I had hoped. In some cases I am getting an error due to the bean not being set because in some business process the bean that is meant to be used in the result page isn't set properly. I suspect that the redirection of the duplicate post reaches the result page faster than the initialization of the bean by the first request. This is a good start though, thank you Guatam.

Comment: I was using an older version of struts before and It had a bug about synchronizing the context that is being redirected for the invalid token. That was why I was getting an NPE before. I updated to version 2.1.3 and used tokenSession interceptor and with a few tweaks I was able to work around the problem. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: thats Great!!..glad i could help